# NextAuth Too many login attempts Email provider error

Tags: next.js, web-applications, next-auth

NextAuth problems with email log in/ sign up

Hi, I am new to nextAuth and I am trying to use the email auth in my app

in my options.ts i have

```
        EmailProvider({
            server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER as string,
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM as string
          }),
```

and in my .env i have

```
EMAIL_SERVER=smtp://username:password@smtp.gmail.com:587
EMAIL_FROM=NextAuth <noreply@example.com>
```

however i keep gettting the error Invalid login: 454-4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. For more information,\n' and the message "the email could not be sent" I am not sure what to do and help is greatly appreciated.